# Arcing text into a U-shape (not in text warp menu)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to warp a string of text into a u-shape where only the top is bent but the bottom stays flat. Like this logo

[image]

but assuming the bottom remained flat and only the top went from big to small back to big.

Think of it as an arc-upper text warp but instead of a hump at the top its flipped upside down to a smile shape.

How to do?

Answer (score 1):

`Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp > Bulge` set to a negative value will suffice in some occasions.

However, realize that using envelopes can sometimes result in undesired alterations. For example, they can occasionally distort verticals in way you don't want.

Many times for good text alterations it requires manual alteration of the forms. I'd say that particular TapOut logo was create by manually making the horizontals fit the desired shapes. You'll notice the first T has a very uneven curve to the top of it, jutting upward at the far left. The bottoms of the A and P do not line up and the bottom of the T on the right is much too curved to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Simply setting "arc upper" to a negative value in illustrator will keep the bottom flat and arc the top in the opposite direction.